# OpencCV: compute image from modified histogram

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image

```
cv::Mat image
```

of which I compute the histogram

```
cv::MatND histogram_original
```

I then modify the histogram (remove unwanted image parts etc), which results in 
another histogram

```
cv::MatND histogram_modified
```

Is it possible to compute the modified image from the modified histogram and the original image?
I currently use masks and a for loop to modify the image parts, but there must be a more elegant way for sure?

Comment: Some code and a few images might help to understand what you want to do

Comment: Sidenote: [MatND is deprecated](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp#L633)

Comment: There are plenty of ways to create a new image that is "similar" to the old image, and have the desired histogram. There's no standard method, though, because it's such an unusual operation. Also, color or greyscale? The latter is _far_ easier. Just calculate the transfer function that transforms the Cumulative Distribution Function and apply that to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get histogram from any images which use finite number of colors. Histogram is a distribution of image pixels with given colors. If we exchange colors of any two points of the image that its histogram is not changed.

So we can't uniquely receive image from histogram. Analogously, if we know changing of histogram, we can't predict changing of original image.